# How to handle main window's keyDown events without pain?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to handle top-level key events for the main window. Is my understanding correct in how I should go about doing it?

1. I can create a `NSWindowController` subclass and override its `keyDown` event (because controllers are a part of the responder chain), and set File Owner of the main NIB to said controller class. Now, because the main window is created in the guts of `NSApplicationMain` and window owner is set to `NSApplication` unconditionally, I have to forgo this and create the main window programmatically with `initWithWindowNibName:`, write some boilerplate to set its delegate, show the window, etc.
2. Another possibility is subclassing `NSWindow` class, override its `keyDown` event and set main window's class to it, but that comes with a host of its own problems: now I need all outlets inside window to actually do something with the event, and it becomes kind of its own controller.

At this point I'm engaging in extreme [yak shaving](http://catb.org/jargon/html/Y/yak-shaving.html) to solve a seemingly simple problem. I suspect this may be due to my inexperience in Cocoa, but is there a better, Proper™ way to do it? I feel like I really should not have to perform these acrobatics.

P.S.

This also applies to `performKeyEquivalent`, as far as I can tell, not only `keyDown`.

Comment: With 27.5K you can be a novice in obj-c, but your SW development will surely come handy.  Actually i didn't understand your problem, whats your requirement. Also read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html), if you haven't.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I just want to be able to respond to keyDown events sent at the main window level (to handle custom shortcuts). And yes, I've read the doc, I get the concepts, but it doesn't address the little "plumbing" problem that I have.

Comment: So here are you. Create a menu and assign keyboard shortcuts..thats it.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya sorry, when I say shortcuts, I pretty much mean arbitrary key presses. For example, `/` is a shortcut (focus search bar). I'd also have to handle arrows, etc. PS, it would also be nice not to have a menu for every key I want to map

Comment: Yeah you can have a menu less(hidden) shortcut. I hope this will suffice.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya but it still doesn't address composition issue, so I don't really know what you mean, sorry. I have to *handle* the key/shortcut event somehow, in one of the two ways I described in the question, do I not? Both of them seem suboptimal.